# Dynamic include classes OR Instantiate objects without including class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

Basically I have a load of classes which are all subviews of UIView.

The app is a (sort of) slideshow application. I want to be able to make lists of potential "routes" that the slides could take in plists.

As such I may have 100s of classes and I don't want to have to include all of them in the potential that I may use one of them once.

So is there a way around this? Can I instantiate a class without including it somehow?

Or am I going to have to include every potential class I'm going to use?

Is there a "global include" like `include all`... clutching at straws here. :p

Thanks
Tom

Comment: *100s of classes* makes me doubt you have a good class design

Comment: Seconded. You mentioned having "lists of potential routes that the slides could take" - are you saying that each route is a separate Objective-C class? If so, that's a badly broken design IMHO.

Comment: 100s was an overstatement! :p but the principals the same. The problem is each "slide" is going to have custom functionality. So one might have a bar graph which animates the bars growing upwards and displaying their values, another might have a video playing, another might have a 'spreadsheet' of sorts calculating a sale of a certain product. etc etc. How else would you do this? Trying to squeeze all of this into one class would be horrendous! (and difficult to change in the future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you have hundreds of classes? It sounds like you have roughly one custom class, which would represent a slide.

Your comment on the question helps. Consider separating the slide from its content. You could have a single slide class which provides the functionality common to all slides, including the ability to manage one or more content objects. Then you'd create a bunch of different content classes: spreadsheet, animatable graph, checklist, whatever. A slide would look at its data to figure out which content class to instantiate.

If you have a common base class for all your content classes, the slide class only needs to know about the base class. The content base class could act as the manager for all the content classes. You could give it a factory method like `-contentForData:(NSData*)data` that returns an appropriate content object for the given data. The slide class doesn't need to know about anything more than the content base class then, so this sort of accomplishes your goal of instantiating your content classes without having to include all their headers in your slide class. The content base class would, of course, still have to know about all the content classes.

It gets a little tricky with the base class needing to know about its subclasses but the subclasses being derived from the base class. I think you can get around this by using a forward @class declaration in the content subclasses.

Comment: Two classes - One to represent a slide, and one to represent its route. Definitely not hundreds though! :-)

Comment: Right. I thought each route might just be an array of slides, but it's hard to say given the available specifications, hence the "roughly". ;-)

Comment: Yes, I have this one slide, however now I need to put in custom structures into each slide. How would you go about this? I thought creating separate UIView slides would be a good idea? Otherwise I'll have to create a class that has EVERY possible eventuality for EVERY possible slide, which is just as much code writing, but all in one huuuuge god-slide class, and I thought the whole point of oop was not to do this. :p

Comment: Perhaps these slides are different from what they sound like. But consider a view that displays a picture. You wouldn't create a separate subclass for each picture you want to display. The picture itself is data that's managed and interpreted by the class, so you have a single class that can display any picture. This is something to strive for when you think you're going to need hundreds of different classes that all do nearly the same thing. Can you describe a bit about your slides and why each needs to be a different class?

Comment: Expanded answer above based on your comment attached to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the class, you must know what set of messages it responds to. Factor out that information into either a common superclass or a protocol, and then you only need to use that.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I instantiate a class without including it somehow?

I guess this is not possible because compiler should definitely see `class` definition in the current scope before using a variable of `class` type.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand your question correctly, you want a single place to put your #include directives so that every class in your project has access to them.  You can do this in the ProjectName_Prefix.pch file.  Any #include or #import statements there will be included in every source code file.

Comment: Kind of, lol. Its a good answer, i didn't realise this before, thank you. :) However, its not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to dynamically ONLY include the classes that represent the slideset in my list, as it were. :)